# three categories item list get with diffrent category_id from json data in recyclerview android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am developing an android app in which i store data from json.

everything is working fine but i am trying to implement multilayout Recyclerview where i show first and second category list items in a box with horizontal scroll and third list which we get from Category_id from json in vertical list

i get data from server in json where category list is open with unique category id just like

```
http://example.com/file_path&Category_id=3
```

and i get json data like

```
json data for category

[  
   {  
      "Category_ID":"3",
      "Category_name":"Camera",
      "Category_image":"upload\/images\/7089-2015-07-09.png"
   },
   {  
      "Category_ID":"9",
      "Category_name":"Cars",
      "Category_image":"upload\/images\/7789-2015-07-09.png"
   },
]
```

json data for category list item

```
category list item json data. Every category list  have  unique id.

[  
   {  
      "Menu_ID":"19",
      "Menu_name":"Sample 6",
      "Price":"380",
      "Menu_image":"upload\/images\/8611-2015-02-11.jpg"
   },
   {  
      "Menu_ID":"18",
      "Menu_name":"Sample 5",
      "Price":"500",
      "Menu_image":"upload\/images\/8119-2015-02-11.jpg"
   }
]
```

i am using recyclerview to show category and by clicking on category item category list is open

but i dont know how to call diffrent category list item from diffrent json category_id in a same recyclerview just like this image

[image: layout image]

Code is something like

MainActivity.java

```
    public class ActivityProductList extends AppCompatActivity {

    List<DataProductAdapter> ListOfdataAdapter;

    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    String HTTP_JSON_URL = "http: //example.com";

    String Menu_Price_JSON = "Price";

    String Menu_ID_JSON = "Menu_ID";

    String Menu_Name_JSON = "Menu_name";

    String Menu_Image_JSON = "Menu_image";

    JsonArrayRequest RequestOfJSonArray ;

    RequestQueue requestQueue ;

    View view ;

    int RecyclerViewItemPosition ;

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManagerOfrecyclerView;

    RecyclerView.Adapter recyclerViewadapter;

    ArrayList<String> ImageTitleNameArrayListForClick;

    public static ArrayList<Long> Menu_ID = new ArrayList<Long>();
    public static ArrayList<String> Menu_name = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<Double> Menu_price = new ArrayList<Double>();
    public static ArrayList<String> Menu_image = new ArrayList<String>();


    ProgressBar prgLoading;
    SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout = null;
    EditText edtKeyword;
    ImageButton btnSearch;
    TextView txtAlert;
    public static double Tax;
    public static String Currency;



    String MenuAPI;
    String TaxCurrencyAPI;
    int IOConnect = 0;
    long Category_ID;
    String Category_name;
    String Keyword;

    // create price format
    DecimalFormat formatData = new DecimalFormat("#.##");

    private RecViewProductAdapter mla;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_product);

        ImageTitleNameArrayListForClick = new ArrayList<>();

        mla = new RecViewProductAdapter(ActivityProductList.this);

        // menu API url
        MenuAPI = examplelink+"&category_id=";

        // tax and currency API url
        TaxCurrencyAPI = examplelink2;

        Intent iGet = getIntent();
        Category_ID = iGet.getLongExtra("category_id",0);
        Category_name = iGet.getStringExtra("category_name");
        MenuAPI += Category_ID;

        ListOfdataAdapter = new ArrayList<>();
        swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipeRefreshLayout);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.orange, R.color.green, R.color.blue);

        prgLoading = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.prgLoading);
        edtKeyword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtKeyword);
        btnSearch = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);
        txtAlert = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtAlert);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_prod);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManagerOfrecyclerView = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManagerOfrecyclerView);
        recyclerViewadapter = new RecViewProductAdapter(ListOfdataAdapter, getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewadapter);


//        JSON_HTTP_CALL();

        new getTaxCurrency().execute();

        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                @Override
                public void onRefresh() {
                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                                IOConnect = 0;

                                clearData();
                                new getDataTask().execute();
                            }
                        }, 3000);
                }
            });

        // Implementing Click Listener on RecyclerView.
        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(
            new RecyclerItemClickListener(this, new   RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(View arg1, int position)
                    {
                        // TODO: Implement this method
                        AdapterView<?> arg0;
                        long arg3;
                        Intent iDetail = new Intent(ActivityProductList.this, ActivityMenuDetail.class);
                        iDetail.putExtra("menu_id", Menu_ID.get(position));
                        startActivity(iDetail);
                    }
                })
        );


    }


    public class getTaxCurrency extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

        // show progressbar first
        getTaxCurrency(){
            if(!prgLoading.isShown()){
                prgLoading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                txtAlert.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // parse json data from server in background
            parseJSONDataTax();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // when finish parsing, hide progressbar
            prgLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            // if internet connection and data available request menu data from server
            // otherwise, show alert text
            if((Currency != null) && IOConnect == 0){
                new getDataTask().execute();
            }else{
                txtAlert.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    }

    public void parseJSONDataTax(){
        try {
            // request data from tax and currency API
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 15000);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(client.getParams(), 15000);
            HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(TaxCurrencyAPI);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            InputStream atomInputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(atomInputStream));

            String line;
            String str = "";
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null){
                str += line;
            }


            // parse json data and store into tax and currency variables
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(str);
            JSONArray data = json.getJSONArray("data"); // this is the "items: [ ] part

            JSONObject object_tax = data.getJSONObject(0); 
            JSONObject tax = object_tax.getJSONObject("tax_n_currency");

            Tax = Double.parseDouble(tax.getString("Value"));

            JSONObject object_currency = data.getJSONObject(1); 
            JSONObject currency = object_currency.getJSONObject("tax_n_currency");

            Currency = currency.getString("Value");


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            IOConnect = 1;
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }

    // clear arraylist variables before used


    // asynctask class to handle parsing json in background
    public class getDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

        // show progressbar first
        getDataTask(){
            if(!prgLoading.isShown()){
                prgLoading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                txtAlert.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // parse json data from server in background
            parseJSONData();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // when finish parsing, hide progressbar
            prgLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            // if data available show data on list
            // otherwise, show alert text
            if(Menu_ID.size() > 0){
                recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(mla);
            }else{
                txtAlert.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

        }
    }

    void clearData(){
        Menu_ID.clear();
        Menu_name.clear();
        Menu_price.clear();
        Menu_image.clear();
    }

    // method to parse json data from server
    public void parseJSONData(){

        clearData();

        try {
            // request data from menu API
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 15000);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(client.getParams(), 15000);
            HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(MenuAPI);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            InputStream atomInputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(atomInputStream));

            String line;
            String str = "";
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null){
                str += line;
            }

            // parse json data and store into arraylist variables
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(str);
            JSONArray data = json.getJSONArray("data"); // this is the "items: [ ] part

            for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject object = data.getJSONObject(i); 

                JSONObject menu = object.getJSONObject("Menu");

                Menu_ID.add(Long.parseLong(menu.getString("Menu_ID")));
                Menu_name.add(menu.getString("Menu_name"));
                Menu_price.add(Double.valueOf(formatData.format(menu.getDouble("Price"))));
                Menu_image.add(menu.getString("Menu_image"));

            }


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //mla.imageLoader.clearCache();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(null);
        super.onDestroy();
    }


    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(final Configuration newConfig)
    {
        // Ignore orientation change to keep activity from restarting
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

}
```

adapter class

```
public class RecViewProductAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecViewProductAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    Context context;

    List<DataProductAdapter> dataAdapters;

    ImageLoader imageLoader;

    private ActivityProductList _mainActivity;

    private Activity activity;


    public RecViewProductAdapter(ActivityProductList activity){
        this._mainActivity=activity;
    }

    public RecViewProductAdapter(Activity act) {
        this.activity = act;
    }

    public RecViewProductAdapter(List<DataProductAdapter> getDataAdapter, Context context){

        super();
        this.dataAdapters = getDataAdapter;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.lsv_item_menu_list, parent, false);

        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);

        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        View convertView = null;
        holder.menuname.setText(ActivityProductList.Menu_name.get(position));
        holder.menuprice.setText(ActivityProductList.Menu_price.get(position)+" "+ActivityProductList.Currency);
        Picasso.with(activity).load(Config.ADMIN_PANEL_URL+"/"+ActivityProductList.Menu_image.get(position)).placeholder(R.drawable.loading).into(holder.imgThumb);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return ActivityProductList.Menu_ID.size();
//        return dataAdapters.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView txtText, txtSubText;
        ImageView imgThumb;
        public TextView menuname, menuprice, menunid;
        public NetworkImageView VollyImageView ;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {

            super(itemView);
            menuname = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtText);
            menuprice = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtSubText);
            imgThumb = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgThumb);

        }
    }
}
```

any idea how can i achieve that layout with above code?

thankx

Comment: The generally recognized java naming convention dictates That class names are capitalized, but variables and methods are NOT capitalized. Please, edit you code to reflect that:: example "RequestOfJSonArray", "ListOfdataAdapter", "ImageTitleNameArrayListForClick", ....and so on. Thank you.

Comment: Directly I see you are passing the `RecyclerViewAdapter` a specific `Activity` - `private MainActivity _mainActivity;`, This is not a good idea then it defeats the idea of object oriented programming.

Comment: @Barns  i edit my code please check

Comment: @Barns  can i add two recyclerview in one adapter?